# How to properly access tuple's members

Tags: c++, tuples

This code updates the rand() value of the tuple every time I access it with std::get, but I want it to be fixed (initialized once). Why doesn't std::get doesn't behave as I expected?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> test(int a)
{
return std::make_tuple(a, rand() % 100);
}

int main()
{
test(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << std::get<1>(test(5)) << '\n';

std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Because you call `std::get` on a new variable each time. Do you want `test` return the same value, or you want your loop to access the same value each time?

Comment: to access the same value each time

Comment: You need to call `test()` with the same argument and get random value once, or you need your loop to print the same value?

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty difficult to understand you but looks like you need this:

```
auto tup = test(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tup) << '\n';
```

then you will access the same value from variable `tup` and you would see that `std::get` does not modify it. But if you call `test()` every time it creates new tuple object, problem is that, not that `std::get` modifies it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to avoid regenerating the random value use a function static variable to create the desired fixed return value once on first call, and return that value after that:

```
std::tuple<int, int> test(int a)
{
    static auto randval = rand() % 100;
    return std::make_tuple(a, randval);
}
```

Since statics are only initialized once, as long as the work can be done at initialization time, the compiler takes care of ensuring it's done only once.

Comment: the problem is, this way, if I call test(6), it will give me the same number as test(5). I want different test(x) to have different random numbers, but always access the same one

Comment: @user1000: Your original question was passing different numbers each time, so I answered in terms of that. If you want to have each new argument cache a different value, it gets more complicated; a `static unordered_map<int, int>` that you `find` each argument in and then update with a newly generated random value if `find` shows the key doesn't exist would allow this.

Comment: Oh you mean a unordered_map inside the tuple?

Comment: @xaxxon: No it wouldn't. The `unordered_map` would be `static`, but not `const`; on each call, you check if the argument has been seen before (does the map have a mapping for it?), and if not, generate the random value and store it in the map. Then use that value (either newly generated, or found in the map) to produce the result `tuple`.

Comment: @user1000: Nope. The `unordered_map` would map arguments to either the random component of the result `tuple` or the whole result `tuple` (depending on needs). Each call would see if the random value exists or not, if it doesn't generate it and store it, then use either the found value or the newly generated one to produce the result.